# Percentage height in a Parent without height specified

Tags: html, css, height

I have a very simple HTML and CSS :

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  paddding: 0;
}

.container {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner-container {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box-1 {
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 150px;
}

.box-2 {
  background: green;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>HEADER</div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <section class="box-1">
    </section>
    <section class="box-2">
    </section>
  </div>
  <div>FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Here's a CodePen for it: https://codepen.io/Loreno/pen/VNZeGw

As you can see, no element in the hierarchy of "box-2" has height specified. 
Becuase of that, box-2's "min-height: 50%" does not work - height is just 0.

How to fix that and get the minimum height behaviour?

Comment: add 100vh height to the `container` - height: 100% won't do

Comment: you should first ask the question: percentage of what?

Comment: Hmmmm no, I see `.box-2` with a height of 50px (a green band), despite it being empty (Chrome). What browser do you use?

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm assuming that the code is actually `min-height:50%` not `px`.

Comment: Ah, right... The good old trick of code not matching the question :)

Comment: @JeremyThille Of course you are right, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Just add edit container css code - instead of height: 100% use height: 100vw;

Short explenation:

vh (viewport height (vw is viewport width)) refers to **DEVICE HEIGHT** (If you want make div fill 50% of **DEVICE WIDTH**, you can just use min-height: 50vw).

% refers to **PARENT**. If you write width: 50%, the div will fill 50% of **PARENT**.

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  paddding: 0;
}

.container {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.inner-container {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box-1 {
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 150px;
}

.box-2 {
  background: green;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>HEADER</div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <section class="box-1">
    </section>
    <section class="box-2">
    </section>
  </div>
  <div>FOOTER</div>
</div>
```